# Given that 2 complex equations share at least one common solution, how can I solve for the unknown coefficient?

Tags: complex-numbers

The subsequent complex equations share at least one common solution.

$z^3-8=0$

$kz^4+2kz^3-2kz^2-6z-24k=0$

Given $k$ is an element of the real number, find the value of $k$

My attempt:

Well first I am thinking form simultaneous equation and then probably use compare the coefficient.

So first I used the algebraic expansion rule:

$z^3-8=0$ is the same as:

$(z-2)(z^2+2z+4) = 0$

I substituted $z=2$ into the second equation and it produced $-12=0$. So I moved on to $(z^2+2z+4)$ and now use quadratic formula on it. This produced $z= -1±\sqrt{3}i$. I then convert this into polar form since if I were to substitute it into second equation, it is going to be easier to work if. And so I did.

Then after (hopefully correct) some algebraic manipulation, I got $k = -2$ and $k =  \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ but both of the solution is part of the real number. I suspect I did the algebra incorrectly whilst expanding but I fail to see where.

Comment: You mean $z^2+2z+4$ surely?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z^3=8$ then
$$kz^4+2kz^3-2kz^2-6z-24k=-2kz^2+(8k-6)z-8k=g(z)$$
say.
Then $$g(2)=-8k+16k-12-8k=-12\ne0$$
as you have observed. The other roots of $z^3-8$ are non-real and solutions
of $z^2+2z+4=0$. If $k$ is real, and $g(z)$ has a root in common with $z^3=8$
then $g(z)$ must be a scalar multiple of $z^2+2z+4$. Therefore
$$g(z)=-2k(z^2+2z+4)$$
as polynomials, and that's equivalent to
$$8k-6=-4k$$
or $k=1/2$.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Sorry it is unclear to me how you got $-2k$ in $g(z) = -2k(z^2+2z+4)$ Why can't I just compare $(z^2+2z+4)$ to $(-2kz^2+(8k-6)z+-8k)$.

Comment: By looking at the leading coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Either $(z -2)$ divides $kz^4 + 2kz^3 -2kz^2  -6z + 24k$ or $(z^2 + 2z + 4)$ does.

Suppose $(z -2)$ divides $kz^4 + 2kz^3 -2kz^2  -6z + 24k$

$\begin{array}{c|rrr}&k&2k&-2k&6&24k\\2&&2k&8k&12k&12k + 6\\\hline\\&k&4k&6k&12k+6&36k + 6\\\end{array}$

$36k+6 = 0\\
k = -\frac 16$

Suppose $(z^2 + 2z + 4)$ divides $kz^4 + 2kz^3 -2kz^2  -6z + 24k.$

Synthetic division is not as easy to apply hear.  But, we can group terms, and find something plausible.

$kz^2(z^2 + 2z + 4) - 6k(z^2 + 2z + 4) = kz^4 + 2kz^3 - 2kz^2 - 12kz - 24k$

And here we clearly have a problem as: $-6 = -12k$ and $-24k =  24k$ are not consistent with each other.

Comment: Hi Mr Doug, thanks for answering but uh where is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The resultant of the polynomials
$$ \eqalign{P_1 &= z^3 - 8\cr
            P_2 &= k{z}^{4}+2\,k{z}^{3}-2\,k{z}^{2}-6\, z - 24\, k}$$
with respect to $z$ is
$$-6912 k^2 + 6912 k - 1728 = -1728 (2k-1)^2$$
so the only $k$ for which they share a common root is $1/2$.

Comment: I appreciate your help Mr Israel but this is a non-calculator question. Thanks again

Comment: Are there calculators that do resultants of polynomials with symbolic coefficients? I might get one!

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bz%5E3-8+%2C+k+z%5E4%2B2+k+z%5E3%E2%88%922+k+z%5E2%E2%88%926+z%E2%88%9224+k%2C+z%5D)